# Javax.measure.quantity.Duration conversion issue

Tags: java, duration, measure, jscience, jsr-275

I am using javax.measure to convert user input to seconds that can vary anywhere from seconds to days, however converting from any unit to another doesn't work, here  is what I have set up.

```
String units = "d";
double value = 30.0;
BaseUnit<Duration> unitType = new BaseUnit<Duration>(units);
UnitConverter toSeconds = unitType.getConverterTo(NonSI.DAY);
double s = toSeconds.convert(Measure.valueOf(value, unitType).doubleValue(unitType));
```

But I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.measure.converter.ConversionException: d is not compatible with s
at javax.measure.unit.Unit.searchConverterTo(Unit.java:259)
at javax.measure.unit.Unit.getConverterTo(Unit.java:248)
at FAMain.main(FAMain.java:18
```

This error comes up for any combination regardless if it is NonSI to NonSI. I can convert Length any way just fine, but for some reason Unit doesn't work.

Comment: what are you trying to do? code looks unreadable mess of different entities. What should be converted to what?

Comment: Sorry, user input should be converted to seconds, and said input can range from seconds to days

Comment: what is user input? what are valid values for user to input?

Comment: The input would be a string called units that is the abbreviation for the unit given, the value of the unit is stored in a double called value, as long as there is a double and a string the input is seen as valid.

Comment: I should add that this is just a snippet of the much larger function designed to show the error I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem that you cannot just create `new BaseUnit<Duration>("d");` and suppose that it will somehow become NonSI.DAY.

probably here is the starting point:

```
public static double toSeconds(final String unit, final double value) {
    switch (unit.toLowerCase()) {
    case "d":
    case "day":
        return NonSI.DAY.getConverterTo(SI.SECOND).convert(value);
    case "m":
    case "minute":
        return NonSI.MINUTE.getConverterTo(SI.SECOND).convert(value);
    case "s":
    case "second":
        return value;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but the confusing thing is that my syntax works for Length, what is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: @pianoisland cannot tell for sure without seeing code

Comment: The length code is exactly what I posted above, just swap out Duration for Length, and any Length class in place of the time classes. Also  Is there any way to fully rely on the javax.measure library to handle unit strings? in the event of getting strings like mins, min, sec, seconds etc?

Comment: @pianoisland I'm not aware about such mappings and doubt that it exists